# Passing parameters to window.addEventListener function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass parameters to a function using

```
window.addEventListener('resize', writeMSG(X, Y));

function writeMSG(x, y){
    console.log("Resize Event"+x+":"+y);
}
```

However this dos not work the event is trigerred only once. If I use just the function name, this calls the function correctly on resize event but I don't have the parameters, (I don't want to put them on global):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', writeMSG);
```

Inside the functon I have the event object... Do I have to pass the parameters inside the event object? Grab the event object and attach the parameters, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a function stub to call your function when the event fires:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
    writeMSG(X, Y);
});
```

The way you were trying to do it, you were calling `writeMSG()` immediately and passing its return value to `addEventListener()` which was certainly not what you wanted (that's why it was only getting called once).

Comment: duh of course you are correct! i am having a serious case of Mondays. Thank you! I will mark it as correct as soon as sf allows me.